# Source for all Windows Phone standard application bar icons (like select, etc)

Tags: windows-phone, icons, selection, application-bar, standard-icons

Windows Phone 8 SDK comes with a set of the standard icons one can use in WP apps (they can be found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Icons\`). However, I could not find the standard 'select' icon used everywhere in the WP interface in this library:

[image]

Is there a public and free source to get this and other standard application bar icons?

Note that in fact this icon is not a monochrome picture I can grab if I make a screenshot of the existing application bar; this icon contains semi-transparent pixels and it is optimized for scaling for WXGA and 720p WP screens though its original size is just 48x48.

Answer (score 4):

I could not find a ready-to-use icon lib in PNG format, but there is a 'workaround', when we can prepare the required icons ourselves. This can be done in a free vector graphics editing app Microsoft Expression Design using high-quality images from a free online graphics lib like http://modernuiicons.com. The site also has a [tutorial](http://modernuiicons.com/tutorial) of how to do that.

However, it would be nice if we could use exactly the standard images the OS itself uses. I think, the whole WP developers community would only benefit if we could use those standard icons without preparing their surrogates manually.

---

An update. Found another similar good resource: http://www.thexamlproject.com/